# Need to make an incrementing Customer ID in Access without Autonumber

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am currently creating a database for our company and I would need to add a Customer ID to each new record.

I designed a [data entry form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ddSK.jpg) and have the following Module running on it to create the ID:

Option Compare Database

Function NewCustomerIDCode() As Long

```
Dim db             As Database
Dim LSQL           As String
Dim LUpdate        As String
Dim Lrs            As DAO.Recordset
Dim LNewCustomerIDCode As Long

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

Set db = CurrentDb()

'Retrieve last number assigned for Customer ID Code
LSQL = "Select Last_Nbr_Assigned from CustomerIDCode"
LSQL = LSQL & " where Code_Desc = 'Customer ID Code'"

Set Lrs = db.OpenRecordset(LSQL)

'If no records were found, return an error
If Lrs.EOF = True Then
    LNewCustomerIDCode = 0
    MsgBox "There was no entry found in the Codes table for Customer ID Code."

Else
    'Determine new Customer ID Code
    LNewCustomerIDCode = Lrs("Last_Nbr_Assigned") + 1

    'Increment Customer ID Code in CustomerIDCode table by 1
    LUpdate = "Update CustomerIDCode"
    LUpdate = LUpdate & " set Last_Nbr_Assigned = " & LNewCustomerIDCode
    LUpdate = LUpdate & " where Code_Desc = 'Customer ID Code'"

    db.Execute LUpdate, dbFailOnError

End If

Lrs.Close
Set Lrs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

NewCustomerIDCode = LNewCustomerIDCode

Exit Function
```

Err_Execute:
    'An error occurred, return 0
    NewCustomerIDCode = 0
    MsgBox "An error occurred while trying to determine the next Customer ID Code to assign."

End Function

The problem is, if for example someone starts entering data in this form an ID is assigned (example: 1023). If for any reason they decide not to finsh the entry and delete the record, the next entry will get number (example: 1024). But I would need 1023 to be reused because it is not linked to a record. For accounting reasons I cannot have this number skip.

On the other hand if the new record is created and for whatever reason is deleted in a year, it's number cannot be reused. For example we delete record 1023 but our last entered record is 1145 the next record should get 1146 and not the deleted n° 1023.

Just for some background info I have a separate Autonumber for the primary key. This is not visible to users and has no meaning to the record except for Access to have a unique number for each record.

Can someone help? I've been searching the net for a day and the only stuff I can find is about autonumbers which does not apply here.

Comment: The most obvious answer is not to delete the record but mark it as deleted. This also deals with your requirement to not reuse a "deleted" records number.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but that isn't really what I was looking for. I need to discard the incomplete input form without saving the customer ID and if I delete an older record the number cannot be reused. I stayed up all night and finally wrote this little query which runs when you click the undo or delete button on the input form :
UPDATE CustomerIDCode SET CustomerIDCode.Last_Nbr_Assigned = DMax("CustomerID","CustomerData");

Comment: Everything works perfectly, and I added a little code to the form to stop the messages asking confirmation to run the query.

Private Sub Form_Load()

   Application.SetOption "Confirm Action Queries", 0
   Application.SetOption "Confirm Document Deletions", 0
   Application.SetOption "Confirm Record Changes", 0
   
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    Application.SetOption "Confirm Action Queries", 1
    Application.SetOption "Confirm Document Deletions", 1
    Application.SetOption "Confirm Record Changes", 1

End Sub

Comment: If you use currentdb.execute "YourQUeryName" dbFailOnError you won't get the warnings at all, so won't need to run all that other code. Additionally, You shouldn't really delete old records, as I said earlier simply have a expired field, and set it when you don't want to see a record. This maintains the history of your process.